# Continuity in $\mathbb{R}^2$ tested by graph.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and define $G : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ by $G(x) =(x, f(x))$. So that the range of $G$ is the graph of $f$. Show that $f$ is continuous

1. if and only if $G$ is continuous
2. if and only if both of the sets $A = \{(x,y): y \leq f(x) \}$ and $B = \{(x,y): y \geq f(x) \}$ are closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

1 is easy, use sequence criterion of continuity.
How to prove 2?

What I have tried: So we can choose the boundary points $Bd = \{(x,y), y=f(x)\}$ in $A$, choose a sequence in $A$ which converges to $Bd$. Similarly, choose sequences in $B$ which converges $Bd$. And use sequence criterion of continuity.

I thought these two kinds of sequences exhaust all kinds of sequences in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I find it's wrong, this process doesn't exhaust all sequences $(x_n, y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow f(x)$ simutaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. Let $(x_n , f(x_n))\to (x_0 ,y) $ then $(x_n ,f(x_n ) )\in A $ and since $A$ is closed we obtain that $(x_0 ,y )\in A$ thus $y\leq f(x_0) .$
   Analogously $(x_n ,f(x_n ) )\in B $ and since $B$ is closed we obtain that $(x_0 ,y )\in B$ thus $y\geq f(x_0) .$

   Hence $f(x_n ) \to y =f(x_0) $ and hence $f$ is continous.

If $f$ is continous then obviously $A$ and $B$ are closed.